# Lambda sin captura no es explícitamente convertida a puntero a función

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, puntero-a-función

Tengo una función que delega la llamada de una función con ciertos parámetros:

```
template <typename ...PARAMETROS>
void llama_funcion_void(void(funcion)(PARAMETROS ...), PARAMETROS ...parametros)
{
    funcion(parametros ...);
}
```

Suponiendo que tengo vairas funciones que coinciden con la firma:

```
void f() { std::cout << "f\n"; }
void f(int i) { std::cout << "f i = " << i << '\n'; }
void f(float f) { std::cout << "f f = " << f << '\n'; }
void f(double d) { std::cout << "f d = " << d << '\n'; }
```

Puedo llamar a `llama_funcion_void` de la siguiente manera:

```
llama_funcion_void<>(f);           // muestra f
llama_funcion_void<int>(f, 1);     // muestra f i = 1
llama_funcion_void<float>(f, 1.f); // muestra f f = 1
llama_funcion_void<double>(f, 1.); // muestra f d = 1
```

Pensé que podía hacer lo mismo proporcionando una lambda a la llamada:

```
llama_funcion_void<>([]() { std::cout << "lambda\n"; });
llama_funcion_void<int>([](int) { std::cout << "lambda i\n"; }, 1);
llama_funcion_void<float>([](float) { std::cout << "lambda f\n"; }, 1.f);
llama_funcion_void<double>([](double) { std::cout << "lambda d\n"; }, 1.);
```

Pero falla al compilar:

> ```
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> note:   mismatched types 'void (*)(PARAMETROS ...)' and 'main()::<lambda()>'
> note:   mismatched types 'void (*)(PARAMETROS ...)' and 'main()::<lambda(int)>'
> note:   mismatched types 'void (*)(PARAMETROS ...)' and 'main()::<lambda(float)'
> note:   mismatched types 'void (*)(PARAMETROS ...)' and 'main()::<lambda(double)>'
> ```

Según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), una lambda sin captura es convertible a puntero a función (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.1.2.6 Expresiones Lambda
>
> El tipo de la [clausura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(inform%C3%A1tica)) para una *expresión-lambda* no genérica sin *captura-de-lambda* **dispone de una función de conversión pública, no-virtual y explícita a puntero a función** con enlazado de C++ **conservando los mismos tipos de retorno y parámetros que el operador de llamada de la clausura**. El valor devuelto por esta función conversión debe ser la dirección de una función que, al ser invocada, tenga el mismo efecto que llamar al operador de llamada de la clausura. [...] Consideremos lo siguiente:
>
> ```
> auto glambda = [](auto a) { return a; }
> int (*fp)(int) = glambda;
> ```
>
> El comportamiento de la función de conversión de `glambda` anterior es el mismo que la siguiente función de conversión:
>
> ```
> struct Closure {
>   template<class T> auto operator()(T t) const { ... }
>   template<class T> static auto lambda_call_operator_invoker(T a) {
>   // redirige la ejecución del operator()(a) y por tanto tiene
>   // el mismo tipo deducido
>   ...
>   }
>   template<class T> using fptr_t =
>      decltype(lambda_call_operator_invoker(declval<T>())) (*)(T);
>   template<class T> operator fptr_t<T>() const
>     { return &lambda_call_operator_invoker; }
> };
> ```
>
> [*Ejemplo*:
>
> ```
> void f1(int (*)(int)) { }
> void f2(char (*)(int)) { }
>
> void g(int (*)(int)) { } // #1
> void g(char (*)(char)) { } // #2
>
> void h(int (*)(int)) { } // #3
> void h(char (*)(int)) { } // #4
>
> auto glambda = [](auto a) { return a; };
> f1(glambda); // Correcto
> f2(glambda); // error: no es convertible
> g(glambda); // error: ambiguo
> h(glambda); // Correcto: llama #3 dado que es convertible
> int& (*fpi)(int*) = [](auto* a) -> auto& { return *a; }; // Correcto
> ```
>
> —*fin del ejemplo* ] [...]

La única manera en que <kbd>[lo he hecho funcionar](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QIBEoKqdMfD8j7lo)</kbd> ha sido usando el operador unario de suma (`+`), que fuerza la conversión implícitamente:

```
llama_funcion_void<>(+[]() { std::cout << "lambda\n"; });                   // muestra lambda
llama_funcion_void<int>(+[](int) { std::cout << "lambda i\n"; }, 1);        // muestra lambda i
llama_funcion_void<float>(+[](float) { std::cout << "lambda f\n"; }, 1.f);  // muestra lambda f
llama_funcion_void<double>(+[](double) { std::cout << "lambda d\n"; }, 1.); // muestra lambda d
```

Pero ¿No debería ser la conversión implícita?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que encuentras en este caso es que el compilador no tiene forma de saber que la especialización explícita que haces del template contiene la lista completa de `PARAMETROS...` y al intentar deducir el resto de parámetros opcionales se ofusca y la deducción falla.

El primer paso que te propondría es sustituir el puntero a función por `std::function`, ya que este objeto suele ser menos restrictivo:

```
template <typename ...PARAMETROS>
void llama_funcion_void(std::function<void(PARAMETROS ...)> funcion, PARAMETROS ...parametros)
{
    funcion(parametros ...);
}
```

Si pruebas el código con este cambio sigues teniendo el problema... vamos a atacar el problema de la deducción de los parámetros:

```
template <typename ...PARAMETROS>
void llama_funcion_void(std::function<void(PARAMETROS ...)> funcion, PARAMETROS ...parametros)
{
    funcion(parametros ...);
}

template<typename ... PARAMETROS, typename FUNCPTR>
void llama_funcion_void(FUNCPTR&& funcion, PARAMETROS ...parametros)
{
    llama_funcion_void(std::function<void(PARAMETROS ...)>(funcion),parametros ...);
}
```

Y voilá el programa empezará a funcionar. Lo que sucede ahora es que esta nueva especialización del template permite al compilador conocer la existencia de la lambda, fuerza una conversión explícita a `std::function` y el resto es historia.

PD.: Hacer lo mismo con punteros a funciones es un poco más engorroso, de hecho algunas pruebas que he realizado han resultado bastante frustrantes.

Comment: Sigo sin comprender cómo se puede deducir el puntero a función explicitando los parámetros en la lista de parámetros de plantilla `llama_funcion_void<double>(f, 1.);` y la misma operación no es posible con una lambda. Fíjate que la función `f` está sobrecargada para diferentes tipos y el compilador escoge la sobrecarga correcta en base a los parámetros de plantilla facilitados.

Comment: En parte es debido a lo que te comenta @Peregring-lk. Una lambda se traduce a clase con operador función (aunque luego el compilador lo convierta en código inline), no a función independiente y esas conversiones pueden ser problemáticas. Por eso te he comentado que es más adecuado usar `std::function`

Comment: Si bien usar `std::function` es una solución, no responde a la pregunta de "*¿Por qué pasa esto?*". El estándar claramente establece que la conversión es implícita, pero sólo funciona con conversión explícita. Es capaz de desambiguar las sobrecargas de `f` mediante la lista de parámetros de plantilla pero no es capaz de inferir el tipo al que debe convertir la lambda sin capturas... ¿no es extraño?.

Comment: La resolución con templates es compleja y más con los _variadic_. En SOen hay varias preguntas tratando problemáticas similares. Supongo que será algo que se irá corrigiendo.

Comment: Si comentas algo sobre las guías de deducción (C++17) podemos dar por completa la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

El uso de la conversión implítica de un tipo a otro requiere que se conozca el tipo del parámetro (es decir, el tipo de destino), y cuando el parámetro es a su vez paramétrico, éste no se conoce, porque se deduce del argumento.

Por tanto, el argumento debe tener forma compatible con el parámetro, sin conversión implícita de por medio.

Para este caso en particular, sencillamente, haz una sobrecarga:

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename ...PARAMETROS>
inline void llama_funcion_void(void(funcion)(PARAMETROS ...),
                               PARAMETROS ...parametros)
{ funcion(parametros ...); }

template<typename... PARAMETROS, class F>
inline void llama_funcion_void(F const& f, PARAMETROS... parametros)
{
    llama_funcion_void(static_cast<void(*)(PARAMETROS...)>(f),
                       parametros...);
}

void f() { std::cout << "f\n"; }
void f(int i) { std::cout << "f i = " << i << '\n'; }
void f(float f) { std::cout << "f f = " << f << '\n'; }
void f(double d) { std::cout << "f d = " << d << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    llama_funcion_void<>(f);           // muestra f
    llama_funcion_void<int>(f, 1);     // muestra f i = 1
    llama_funcion_void<float>(f, 1.f); // muestra f f = 1
    llama_funcion_void<double>(f, 1.); // muestra f d = 1

    llama_funcion_void<>([]() { std::cout << "lambda\n"; });
    llama_funcion_void<int>([](int) { std::cout << "lambda i\n"; }, 1);
    llama_funcion_void<float>([](float) { std::cout << "lambda f\n"; }, 1.f);
    llama_funcion_void<double>([](double) { std::cout << "lambda d\n"; }, 1.);

    return 0;
}
```

Así, la función pasada, o tiene la forma requerida, o es convertible a la forma requerida, incluso explícitamente. Si necesitas que el objecto pasado sea implícitamente convertible, entonces tu segunda sobrecarga debe provocar la conversión implícita:

```
template<typename... PARAMETROS, class F>
inline void llama_funcion_void(F const& f, PARAMETROS... parametros)
{
    void(*f_convertida)(PARAMETROS...) = f;
    llama_funcion_void(f_convertida, parametros...);
}
```

Es exáctamente el mismo motivo por el que no puedes hacer uso del `operator<<` para clases convertibles a `std::string`s, pero sí para clases convertibles a `char const*`:

```
struct A { operator std::string() const { return "hola"; } };
struct B { operator char const*() const { return "hola"; } };

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;

   // No lo he compilado pero fallará
   std::cout << a << std::endl;

   // No lo he compilado pero no fallará
   std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

La cabecera `std::string` ofrece una sobrecarga del `operator<<`, pero es una sobrecarga paramétrica sobre `std::basic_string<T>`. El objecto de tipo `A` es convertible a `std::string`, pero ¡el parámetro no es un `std::string`! El tipo del parámetro no existe, hay que deducirlo a través del argumento. Cuando el parámetro se conoce, entonces se intenta adaptar el argumento (conversión). Cuando no, se intenta adaptar el parámetro (deducción). Supongo que, permitir "conversión + deducción" haría demasiado grande el árbol de prueba y ralentizaría la compilación, o simplemente que es una fuente de ambigüedades importante.

Sin embargo, `std::ostream` tiene una sobrecarga no paramétrica para `char const*`, por eso el objecto `b` si se convierte-imprime satisfactoriamente.

Comment: Ya se que una lambda no es una función. Ya se que es un funtor que hace uso del operador paréntesis... de hecho incluso he citado el estándar de C++ donde se indica eso.

Comment: Perdona. Está claro que decidí no leer la segunda mitad de la pregunta. Ahora esto sí que te responde, o eso creo.

Comment: La respuesta tiene ahora bastante mejor pinta